# Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Clinical.Infrastructure.Scheduling.Reminders.Services.SendReminderEmails

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-web-api

I'm getting the below error while executing the project.
I'm trying to use Quartz for job scheduling.

> System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be
> constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor
> 'ServiceType:
> Clinical.Infrastructure.Scheduling.Reminders.Services.SendReminderEmails
> Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType:
> Clinical.Infrastructure.Scheduling.Reminders.Services

[image]

**Program.cs**

```
using CcAcca.ApplicationInsights.ProblemDetails;
using Clinical;
using Clinical.Application;
using Clinical.Application.Sockets;
using Clinical.Domain.TemplateAggregate;
using Clinical.Infrastructure.Scheduling.Reminders.Services;
using Clinical.Infrastructure.Scheduling.Reminders;
using H1.Clinical.Api;
using Hellang.Middleware.ProblemDetails;
using Kernel;
using Kernel.Messaging;
using Kernel.Mongo;
using Kernel.Web;
using Kernel.Web.Authentication;
using MassTransit;
using MassTransit.SignalR;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;
using Microsoft.FeatureManagement;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Quartz.Impl;
using Quartz.Spi;
using Quartz;
using Serilog;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Configuration.AddEnvironmentVariables();

var jwtSettings = new JwtBearerSettings();
builder.Configuration.Bind(nameof(JwtBearerSettings), jwtSettings);

try
{
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .CreateBootstrapLogger();

    builder.Host.UseSerilog((hostingContext, service, loggerConfiguration) => loggerConfiguration
        .WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(service.GetRequiredService<TelemetryConfiguration>(), TelemetryConverter.Traces)
        .WriteTo.Console()
        .Filter.ByExcluding(e => e.Exception is TaskCanceledException)
        .ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration));

    Log.Information("healthONE Clinical application starting up");

    builder.Services.AddSignalR(o =>
    {
        o.HandshakeTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
        o.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
    });
    var section = builder.Configuration.GetSection(nameof(MemorySettings));
    builder.Services.Configure<MemorySettings>(section);

    var memorySettings = new MemorySettings();
    section.Bind(memorySettings);

    builder.Services
        .AddHealthChecks()
        .AddProcessAllocatedMemoryHealthCheck(memorySettings.MaxMemoryInMb);
    builder.Services.AddControllers();
    builder.Services.AddFeatureManagement();

    builder.Services
        .AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(options => { options.EnablePerformanceCounterCollectionModule = false; })
        .AddProblemDetailTelemetryInitializer()
        .AddEndpointsApiExplorer()
        .AddJwtAuthentication(jwtSettings);

    builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen((Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenOptions c) =>
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1",
            new OpenApiInfo
            {
                Title = "healthONE Clinical API",
                Version = "v1",
                Description = "Modular Clinical API"
            });
        c.EnableAnnotations();
        c.UseAllOfForInheritance();
        c.SelectSubTypesUsing(baseType =>
        {
            if (baseType == typeof(ITemplateField))
            {
                return new List<Type>()
                {
                    typeof(MultiLineText),
                    typeof(Canvas),
                    typeof(Dropdown),
                    typeof(RadioButtonGroup),
                    typeof(SingleLineText),
                    typeof(CheckboxGroup),
                    typeof(TimePicker),
                    typeof(DatePicker)
                };
            }

            return Enumerable.Empty<Type>();
        });
    });

    builder.Services
        .RegisterKernelDependencies()
        .RegisterWebKernel(builder.Environment)
        .RegisterMongoKernel(builder.Configuration, schemaCreatorLocation: null)
        .RegisterClinical(builder.Configuration)
        .RegisterMessaging(
            builder.Configuration,
            options =>
            {
                options.AddSignalRHub<DiaryHub>();
                options.AddSignalRHub<ConsultationHub>();
                options.AddSignalRHub<ArchiveHub>();
                options.AddConsumersFromNamespaceContaining(typeof(ClinicalApplicationModule));
            });

    builder.Services.AddHostedService<QuartzHostedService>();
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<IJobFactory, SingletonJobFactory>();
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<ISchedulerFactory, StdSchedulerFactory>();

    builder.Services.AddSingleton<SendReminderEmails>();
    builder.Services.AddSingleton(new EmailSenderJob(type: typeof(SendReminderEmails), expression: "0/30 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *"));
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Log.Fatal(ex, "An unhandled exception occured during bootstrapping");
    throw;
}
finally
{
    Log.Debug("Shut down complete");
    Log.CloseAndFlush();
}

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();
app.UseProblemDetails();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();
}

app.UseAuthentication();

app.MapHealthChecks("/healthz");

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();
app.MapHub<DiaryHub>("hubs/clinical/diary");
app.MapHub<ConsultationHub>("hubs/clinical/consultation");
app.MapHub<ArchiveHub>("hubs/clinical/archive");

app.Run();
```

**Error** :

```
System.AggregateException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Clinical.Infrastructure.Scheduling.Reminders.Services.SendReminderEmails Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: Clinical.Infrastructure.Scheduling.Reminders.Services.SendReminderEmails': Cannot consume scoped service 'Clinical.Infrastructure.Emails.IAppointmentEmailSender' from singleton 'Clinical.Infrastructure.Scheduling.Reminders.Services.SendReminderEmails'.)
  Source=Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(ICollection`1 serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionContainerBuilderExtensions.BuildServiceProvider(IServiceCollection services, ServiceProviderOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.DefaultServiceProviderFactory.CreateServiceProvider(IServiceCollection containerBuilder)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.ServiceFactoryAdapter`1.CreateServiceProvider(Object containerBuilder)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.CreateServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplicationBuilder.Build()
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in E:\Altron\Altron-Backend\src\H1\Clinical.Api\Program.cs:line 133

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]

Inner Exception 1:
InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Clinical.Infrastructure.Scheduling.Reminders.Services.SendReminderEmails Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: Clinical.Infrastructure.Scheduling.Reminders.Services.SendReminderEmails': Cannot consume scoped service 'Clinical.Infrastructure.Emails.IAppointmentEmailSender' from singleton 'Clinical.Infrastructure.Scheduling.Reminders.Services.SendReminderEmails'.

Inner Exception 2:
InvalidOperationException: Cannot consume scoped service 'Clinical.Infrastructure.Emails.IAppointmentEmailSender' from singleton 'Clinical.Infrastructure.Scheduling.Reminders.Services.SendReminderEmails'.
```

**SendReminderEmails.cs**

```
using Quartz;
using Kernel.Users;
using Clinical.Infrastructure.Emails;
using Clinical.Domain.ReminderAggregate;
using Clinical.Infrastructure.Emails.Models;

namespace Clinical.Infrastructure.Scheduling.Reminders.Services
{
    public class SendReminderEmails : IJob
    {
        private readonly IReminderRepository reminderRepository;

        private readonly IAppointmentEmailSender appointmentEmailSender;
        public SendReminderEmails(IReminderRepository reminderRepository,
            IAppointmentEmailSender appointmentEmailSender)
        {
            this.reminderRepository = reminderRepository;
            this.appointmentEmailSender = appointmentEmailSender;
        }

        public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
            var reminders = await reminderRepository.GetAllRemindersofToday();
            foreach (var reminder in reminders)
            {
                //var email = reminder.Email;

                var recipientEmailAddress = Email.TryMake("aliwaheed51@gmail.com"/*patientBooking.Email*/);
                //if (recipientEmailAddress is null)
                //    return BadRequest($"'{patientBooking.Email}' is not a valid {nameof(Email)}");
                var recipients = new RecipientsModel
                {
                    primaryRecipientEmail = recipientEmailAddress
                };

                await appointmentEmailSender.SendEmail(recipients, "Ali Waheed" /*userContext.Current.FullName*/, "scheduled");
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you could replace the image with the bit of code, that is causing the exception, that would be great. Screen readers and visually impaired people have a hard time parsing that bit of information, if it is in binary format, instead of plain text.

Comment: 1) please post the full error text 2) please do not post code as images.

Comment: Also please add the definition for `SendReminderEmails`

Comment: More Information is added please have a look your help will be really appreciated.